# how to delete this folder show long path error

Tags: windows-7

I am trying to delete this folder but its show the error that is long path can you fix it out ?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do a live boot from a linux distro such as ubuntu and then delete it.

Comment: Did you try from ubuntu?